# Determine If Device Has GPU

Tags: android, performance

My Device is Huawei G600 and it does not have GPU . and it is the device that ai run all of my tests on.

I know that if we target the api>13 it will automatically turn the hardware acceleration on.and of course it will cause to repopulate the changed portions of the display list and that is something heavy for devices like mine that does not have GPU but it is assumed that it has . and when i turn hardware acceleration off in manifest it has huge performance and smoothness upgrades and the animation run smoothly . but i want the hardware acceleration to be on for the devices that have GPU.

so i should determine somehow that if a device has GPU at runtime and enable it for the Window.

so How????

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

to your AndroidManifest in `<application` tag, HAC will be automatically enabled for devices that support it.

Comment: I knew it already , this is not my answer.even if i dont turn on HA in manifest , it will be turned on automatically by system.in my device i dont have GPU and GPU options in the Developers Settings  such as showing touch updates.and when it is turned on either by me or auto , it has just over head for the app computing and no use!

if i turn it off explicitly from manifest its OK , but i want the other devices having GPU to take advantage of their device.